# Can't catch more than one interrupt

Tags: c, signals

I want my program to run in a loop until it receives an alarm signal, in the meantime I want to run some code every time it receives an interrupt signal.

The following almost works:

```
bool volatile waiting = true;
bool volatile interrupted = false;

void catch_interrupt(int x)
{
    interrupted = true;
}

void catch_alarm(int x)
{
    waiting = false;
}

void alive()
{
    signal(SIGINT, catch_interrupt);
    signal(SIGALRM, catch_alarm);
    alarm(10);

    while (waiting)
    {
        if (interrupted)
        {
            printf("interrupted\n");
            interrupted = false;
        }
    }

    printf("done\n");
}
```

The problem is that it only works for the first interrupt signal. The second interrupt kills the program (without printing "done") regardless.

So the output I see is

```
^Cinterrupted
^C
```

when I want to see

```
^Cinterrupted
^Cinterrupted
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `signal()` to install custom signal handlers, as its behavior in that case varies across implementations.  In particular, on some systems, if `signal()` is used to set a custom signal handler for a given signal, then that signal's disposition is reset when the signal is received.  That's what you seem to be observing, but you cannot portably rely on it.

Instead, install signal handlers via `sigaction()`.  Among other things, it has a mechanism for specifying whether the handler should be reset upon receipt of the signal.

Answer (score 2):

Signal handlers set with `signal()` are disarmed when the signal handler is called in response to a signal. You have to rearm the signals each time:

```
void catch_interrupt(int x)
{
    interrupted = true; 
    signal(SIGINT, catch_interrupt);

}

void catch_alarm(int x)
{
    waiting = false;
    signal(SIGALRM, catch_alarm);
}
```

Yes, that means there is a small window of vulnerability when the first signal has been handled but the handler has not yet been reinstated when a second signal will cause the program to react as if no signal handler is installed (because no signal handler *is* installed).

Comment: Ugh, I suspected as much. Where is this documented?

Comment: @Max Try `man signal`. My (Linux) manual page describes it quite clearly.

Comment: I don't know. I remember noticing this problem about 18 years ago when I was coding on old HP workstations. We figured out that rearming the signal was doing what we expected. Learn by carrot and stick :) And John answer is probably better since it's not 20 year old.